# What is the difference between PubSub.Subscriptions() and Topic.getSubscriptions() in Google PubSub?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

I've created a program that handles PubSub messaging using the Google PubSub [NodeJS SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/pubsub).
While developing this I noticed that the NodeJS Library and docs show two ways of retrieving active subscriptions in Google PubSub:

1. `PubSub.subscriptions('SubscriptionName')` [docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#receive_messages)
2. `PubSub.topic('TopicName).getSubscriptions()` [docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#listing_subscriptions)

I understand that the 2nd option might only list subscriptions related to a topic, but I'm more interested in the workings behind the scene.

In my first attempt I used the 2nd option to retrieve my subscriptions and that worked while running the application, but I ran into timeouts when trying to mock the call in my unit tests and I couldn't fix it. I switched to the 1st approach which doesn't use a Promise and just returns a plain Subscription object, this did work in my unit tests just fine

Are there downsides to not using the promise based call as it might not yield the most up to date results? If not, is there a reason why there are two options and one is promise based and the other is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two APIs do very different things. The first [one creates a Subscription object in the client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/e494fb7303ae58b08f3f75aa87ea1f10c86f648e/src/pubsub.ts#L1179) that can be used for receiving messages. It does not retrieve any state from the Cloud Pub/Sub service. Therefore, there is no asynchronous work to do and it need not return a promise. The second one actually [goes to the Cloud Pub/Sub service, retrieves the list of subscriptions for the topic, and creates a Subscription object for each one](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/e494fb7303ae58b08f3f75aa87ea1f10c86f648e/src/topic.ts#L593-L605).

If you know the name of the subscription for which you want to receive messages and can be reasonably confident that it exists, then use `PubSub.subscriptions('SubscriptionName')`. If you try to start receiving messages on this subscription by calling `subscription.on('message', messageHandler);` and it doesn't exist, then an error is emitted.

If you don't know the name of the subscription and instead need to fetch the list and choose the subscription from which to receive messages from the list of all subscriptions for the topic, then use the `PubSub.topic('TopicName).getSubscriptions()` call.

For further help with why mocking the `getSubscriptions()` call didn't work, would probably need to see the code you were using to mock it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, does this mean that there could be a downside to only creating a subscription on the client instead of on the pub/sub service itself?

Comment: Neither of these APIs creates subscriptions in the Pub/Sub service. To do that, you need to actually [create one](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#creating_subscriptions).

Comment: Ah right, okay then I should re-phrase, is there a downside to not retrieving the list of subscriptions for topics from the Cloud Pub/Sub service?

Comment: Nope, no downside at all. I would say don't retrieve the list of subscriptions from the server unless you actually need the list because, for example, you don't know the name of the subscription.